# ResponseStatusException can only handle Controller layer execption? can not handle execption from interceptor throwed

Tags: spring-boot

when i thrown ResponseStatusException from controller, responsebody can normaly gererate，but when i thrown ResponseStatusException in interceptor, responseboy is empty.
can you help me, thank you very much. sorry for my bad english

Comment: Please share your code snippet.

Comment: snippet is already post, thankyou very much

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class AuthenticationInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor throws Execption {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
        String authenticationHeader = request.getHeader("Authentication");
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(authenticationHeader) || !authenticationHeader.startsWith("token")) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "no token");
        }
        String[] tokens = authenticationHeader.split(" ");
        if (tokens.length != 2) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "token format exception");
        }
        String token = tokens[1];
        //todo with token

        return true;
    }
}
```

when i use postman call a getrequest `localhost:8081/login`

the terminal represent message like this
2021-04-01 08:37:54.530  WARN 22288 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] .w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException: 401 UNAUTHORIZED "no token"]
2021-04-01 08:37:54.549  WARN 22288 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] .w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException: 401 UNAUTHORIZED "no token"]

but not format execption to json response.